# Processing 3.0 launch() function doesn't launch my .exe

Tags: processing, exe, launch

Processing 3.0 launch function doesn't launch my .exe.

I am using the Launch() function (https://processing.org/reference/launch_.html)

```
launch("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe");
```

Or

```
launch("C:/app/keyboard.exe");
```

Result: Chrome browser will open. keyboard.exe will not. I've tryed different locations  and relative paths.
I only get a windows loader when the link is correct. So that is correct.

The function discriptions says this:
"Be sure to make the file executable before attempting to open it (chmod +x). "

https://superuser.com/questions/106181/equivalent-of-chmod-to-change-file-permissions-in-windows

I also made a .bat file to execute the .exe but the launch() function only works on exe files.

but that didnt work either.

System:

- Processing 3.0
- Java 8
- Windows 10, 64 bit

So what am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that `C:/app/keyboard.exe` is the location of the executable? Can you run it from the command prompt?

Comment: while technically windows itself doesn't care about / (unix delimiter) and \ (windows delimiter), Processing might. The reference page shows unix paths, on Windows try `launch("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");` instead (\\, because you're using \ in a string, which is the escape character)

Comment: Yes, the keyboard.exe is there. (bad links don't show the windows spinning wheel and yes I can launch using cmd). I've tried the whole // or \\ combinations but none of them worked. And it even if.. it doens't explain why Chrome does launch.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit dodgy but works in windows 8:

```
PrintWriter output=null;
output = createWriter("myfile.bat");
output.println("cd "+sketchPath(""));
output.println("start  archivo.exe");
output.flush();
output.close();  
output=null;
launch(sketchPath("")+"myfile.bat");
```

And you can choose another relative or absolute path
for instance

output.println("cd ..");
   output.println("cd directoriy");
...

Answer (score 0):

As Samuil advises, Windows uses `\` instead of a `/` as a separator character, which you'll need to escape, hence `\\`: `launch("C:\\app\\keyboard.exe");`

I recommend using [File.separator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator):

```
launch("C:"+File.separator+"app"+File.separator+"keyboard.exe");
```

It's a bit longer, but will work regardless of the operating system(Linux/OSX/Windows/etc.).

Aside [launch()](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#launch-java.lang.String...-), also try [exec()](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#exec-java.lang.String...-):

```
exec(new String[]{"start","C:"+File.separator+"app"+File.separator+"keyboard.exe");
```

also [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html?is-external=true). (If you need to check the output, you may need to write your own thread that will pipe the output)